# how to use Symfony Class Loader

Tags: php, symfony, classloader

I have the following structure

api

common

config

docs

scripts

vendor

I put custom autoloader under common/php/autoload.php which contains

```
<?php
require_once BASE_DIR . 'vendor/autoload.php';
require_once BASE_DIR . 'vendor/symfony/class-loader/ClassLoader.php';

use Symfony\ClassLoader\ClassLoader;

$loader = new \ClassLoader();

// to enable searching the include path (eg. for PEAR packages)
$loader->setUseIncludePath(true);

// ... register namespaces and prefixes here - see below

$loader->register();

// register a single namespaces
$loader->addPrefix('CCP', BASE_DIR . 'common/ccp/');


// cache files locations
require_once BASE_DIR . 'vendor/symfony/class-loader/ApcClassLoader.php';

// sha1(__FILE__) generates an APC namespace prefix
$cachedLoader = new ApcClassLoader(sha1(__FILE__), $loader);

// register the cached class loader
$cachedLoader->register();

// deactivate the original, non-cached loader if it was registered previously
$loader->unregister();
```

As you may know composer places everything under ROOTDIR/vendor folder.

```
Error I get is Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'ClassLoader' not found in ROOTDIR/common/php/autoload.php:7
```

**UPDATE**

When I try to load my custom class under common/ccp it does not load.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'CCP\Notification' not found in ROOTDIR/scripts/cli-test-email.php:12
```

contents of class

```
<?php
namespace CCP

class Notification{
...
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

My scripts is under `script` folder. If I add the `use` it doesn't error but nothing happens in terms of echo or any errors. If I remove the `use` it doesn't find the class `Notification`.

```
#!/opt/SP/php-7.0.10/bin/php -q
<?php
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT);
echo "before use";
use CCP/Notification;
echo "after use";

$notification = new Notification();

print_r($notification);
$notification->emailTest();
```

Comment: `$loader = new Symfony\Component\ClassLoader\ClassLoader`

Comment: why do I have to include `Symfony\Component\ClassLoader\`?

Comment: Things you may want look up: how namespaces works and what's psr-0/4

Comment: The symfony class loader is depreciated in 3.3 and will be going away in 4.0.  I can't think of any reason why you would want to use it.  Might be looking at some very old tutorials?  And yes once you have required vendor/autoload.php then you need not require anything else. http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/class_loader.html

Comment: @Cerad I put comment on below answer. So I am using turotial http://jessesnet.com/development-notes/2014/php-composer-autoloading/ which worked for me. is this up to date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indtead of this:

```
use Symfony\ClassLoader\ClassLoader;

$loader = new \ClassLoader();
```

You should do either:

```
$loader = new Symfony\ClassLoader\ClassLoader();
```

or:

```
use Symfony\ClassLoader\ClassLoader;

$loader = new ClassLoader(); //no backslash at the begining
```

When you put a backslash in front of classname, it means the root namespace, so it doesn't matter that you put `use` before, because it's not used here.

As an example let's assume you have two classes with the same name `SomeClass`. One of them is under root namespace, and the another is under `Some/Namespace/SomeClass`

Now:

```
use Some/Namespace/SomeClass;

$object1 = new SomeClass(); //this is Some/Namespace/SomeClass instace
$object2 = new \SomeClass(); //this is SomeClass from root namespace.
```

**EDIT:**

As for your issue in your updated question - it may be related to case sensitivity. Try to make your directories names match namespace, including case sensitivity.

Comment: I renamed common/ccp to common/CCP but still same issue

Comment: I couldn't get this to work plus i see symfony autoload is being depreciated so I used composer instead which is working for me http://jessesnet.com/development-notes/2014/php-composer-autoloading/